# req.header vs req.headers in Express

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am using Express with Body Parser. Given a below header key:

> **`X-Master-Key`**

When I am using the below code snippet, it fails to output the value

```
req.headers['X-Master-Key'] // Fails
```

but when the above is changed to, it works

```
req.headers['x-master-key'] // Works
```

Further, when I tried to output `req.headers`, it turns out that Express outputs all the headers in a down-case format.

---

I started digging down further and tried using the below code, either of these snippets work

```
req.header('X-Master-Key'); // Works

// -- OR

req.header('x-master-key'); // Works
```

---

So what's the issue here? Why does Express changes all header keys to down-case? Moreover, how using `req.header()` is different from `req.headers[]`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem arises because in the HTTP protocol, headers are case-insensitive. This means that `content-type`, `Content-Type`, and `coNTEnt-tYPe` all refer to the same header, and the Express framework needs to be able to handle any of them.

The different between `req.headers` (the object) and `req.header` (the function) is simply this:

If you want to get a property from a Javascript object, the property name is case-sensitive. So `req.headers['content-type']` will work; `req.headers['Content-Type']` will not. Why does the lower case version work? Because the Express framework, in an attempt to handle all the different possible cases (remember, HTTP will allow anything), converts everything to lower case.

But the developers of Express recognize that you (the developer) might be looking for `Content-Type` and you might not remember to convert to lower case, so they provided a function, `req.header`, which will take care of that for you.

So, in short:

This is recommended:

```
const myHeader = req.header('Content-Type');
```

Use whatever case you want - the function will convert it to lower case and look up the value in `req.headers`.

This is not recommended:

```
const myHeader = req.headers['Content-Type'];
```

If you don't use a lower-case header name, you won't get what you expect.

Comment: *converts everything to lower case* - That's what I was looking for. Some context: I was revamping some API I wrote 3 years back, so I was looking to build things in the right way, `req.headers` was surely confusing and I was expecting someone to recommend me `req.header()` over it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This answer is another good example, that specification is not always same as implementation. Flavours exist, especially if tool is opinionated. Of course I believe majority of teams of developers strive to conform to specification whatever the specification would be.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes down to case-sensitivity.

When you look at the [documentation for `req.get`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get) (which is aliased by `req.header`), it states:

> Returns the specified HTTP request header field (case-insensitive match). The Referrer and Referer fields are interchangeable.

The [w3 standard](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) indicates that headers should be case-insensitive:

> Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.

So it would appear that node http module, which express uses, just treats them all as lower-case to "save you steps" according to this [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1954#issuecomment-2552895)

[You can see](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/request.js#L20) that the `express` framework `req` object actually utilizes the node module `http`:

```js
var accepts = require('accepts');
var deprecate = require('depd')('express');
var isIP = require('net').isIP;
var typeis = require('type-is');
var http = require('http');
var fresh = require('fresh');
var parseRange = require('range-parser');
var parse = require('parseurl');
```

Furthermore, in the code you can see that the `req.header` method converts whatever you give it to lower-case:

```js
req.get =
req.header = function header(name) {
  if (!name) {
    throw new TypeError('name argument is required to req.get');
  }

  if (typeof name !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('name must be a string to req.get');
  }

  var lc = name.toLowerCase();

  switch (lc) {
    case 'referer':
    case 'referrer':
      return this.headers.referrer
        || this.headers.referer;
    default:
      return this.headers[lc];
  }
};
```

Finally, the `http` module parses headers using the [`matchKnownFields`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/388cef61e8a4859b7505f7b5cf988eba27ce17b4/lib/_http_incoming.js#L156)  function which automatically lower-cases any and all headers that aren't "traditional headers", in which case it is case-insensitive.

Here is the responsible snippet, that implements the behavior you are seeing:

```js
if (lowercased) {
    return '\u0000' + field;
} else {
    return matchKnownFields(field.toLowerCase(), true);
}
```

Comment: As you mentioned, `req.headers` is case-sensitive, also Express doesn't change the case, so why it doesn't match `req.headers['X-Master-Key']` ?

Comment: On second look, you may be correct. I looked further and it's actually due to the node module `http`: [HTTP headers are being converted to lower-case](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1954#issuecomment-2552895). It looks like they did this to align with the [W3 standard section 4.2](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have updated my answer with quite a lot more information that should explain in good detail what's happening.

Comment: This is insightful, thank you for sharing the info.

Answer (score 0):

A short summary of the difference between `req.headers` and `req.header`:

**`req.headers`** is the [`message.headers`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageheaders) object from [`Node#http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module where the fields are lower-cased. And so, since `headers` is a plain JS object, the properties are case-sensitive.

**`req.header`** (alias `req.get`) is an [Express function](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get) that [converts](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/94669f9289fdd1c640b0c35acf4d9f8e996a646c/lib/request.js#L74) the parameters to lower-case before accessing the value. So the headers could be accessed in a case-insensitive manner. For eg. it's perfectly alright to do `req.header('x-MaSTeR-KEy');` and it'd work because it'd internally get converted to `x-master-key`.